# Manipulating vector into a data frame using strsplit()

Tags: r

I have received some data in a pretty horrible format so I wish to manipulate it into a better format to work with. My goal here is to split the data out and put it back into a data frame in position order. For example here I have 10 numbers then a forward slash, I wish to get this into a data frame with each colum indication a position in the original data, which would look like the df at the bottom of the question, I'm just not sure how to get from the version where I have split my data by position into df form.

```
 mydata
 "/0,2,5,6,2,5,0,0,0,0/0,0,8,1,4,,2,4,0,0/5,6,2,5,0,0,7,8,3,2\"

 mydata #step1
 [[1]]
 [1] "0"  "2"   "5"   "6"   "2"   "5"   "0"  "0"    "0"   "0"

[[2]]
 [1] "0"  "0"   "8"   "1"   "4"   "0"   "2"   "4"   "0"   "0"

[[3]]
 [1] "5"  "6"    "2"  "5"   "0"   "0"   "7"   "8"   "3"   "2"

mydf
p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p7  p8  p0  p10
0   2   5    6   2   5   0   0   0   0
0   0   8    1   4   0   2   4   0   0
5   6   2    5   0   0   7   8   3   2
```

Sorry its not the best phrased question, feel free to do anything you want with the original data, it doesn't have to be split I just thought that was a good way of getting started

Comment: Is the backslash at the end of your string intentional?

Comment: Given the presence of backslashes in the string, your comment under my answer, and me wondering if `mydata` starts with a literal double-quote, it would be clarifying if you provided the real `mydata` object. Also, your suggested presence of `\20:40` (comment, below) is also a little perplexing ...

Comment: Yep that would make sense then, the `\"` does confuse me but that makes more sense, in that case the string would look like '"stat=\"20:40/0,2,5,6,2,5,0,0,0,0/0,0,8,1,4,,2,4,0,0/5,6,2,5,0,0,7,8,3,2\""`. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the backslash in your `mydata` should be a forward slash, we can replace the forward slashes with newlines and use `read.csv`.

```r
mydata <- "/0,2,5,6,2,5,0,0,0,0/0,0,8,1,4,,2,4,0,0/5,6,2,5,0,0,7,8,3,2/"
dat <- read.csv(text = gsub("/", "\n", mydata), header = FALSE)
dat
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1  0  2  5  6  2  5  0  0  0   0
# 2  0  0  8  1  4 NA  2  4  0   0
# 3  5  6  2  5  0  0  7  8  3   2
```

You demonstrated a `0` in the middle, currently an `NA` (due to the empty cell in `mydata`), we can fix that easily with:

```r
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(z) ifelse(is.na(z), 0, z))
dat
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1  0  2  5  6  2  5  0  0  0   0
# 2  0  0  8  1  4  0  2  4  0   0
# 3  5  6  2  5  0  0  7  8  3   2
```

If you really want to use `strsplit`, however, we can have mostly the same effect with

```r
out <- strsplit(mydata, "/")[[1]] |>
  strsplit(",") |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _) |>
  as.data.frame()
out
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# 1  0  2  5  6  2  5  0  0  0   0
# 2  0  0  8  1  4     2  4  0   0
# 3  5  6  2  5  0  0  7  8  3   2
```

Which is now a frame of strings. We can do a similar post-processing as above (`out[] <- lapply(...)`) to convert the empty/null to `0`.

Comment: If it is a real backslash, then your example is incomplete R code, since that string never ends. *Edit*: okay, I was assuming that the leading double-quote is indicating the start-of-string for R. Is there a literal double-quote starting the string as well?

Comment: Starting with my code, one could also do `gsub("[\\\\/]", "\n", mydata)` to convert both single-backslashes (not a backslash that is escaping the next character) and forward slashes to newlines.

Comment: And just a word about the `args = _` in do.call(rbind, for those wondering..., oh, dots, well wondering. About the notation.

Comment: `_` is native pipe notation for "put the previous results here". The implicit/default use is to put the previous data as the first argument, as in `1:10 |> mean()`, which could be written as `1:10 |> mean(x = _)` or `1:10 |> mean(na.rm = TRUE, x = _)`. Does that help?

Comment: Absolutely, ?`|>`, (rtm), there's more there than meets the unread eye.

Comment: FYI @Chris, in the absence of the explicit `_` placeholder, `|>` will place the data as the first argument not explicitly used. For instance, in my code above, I could instead have done `|> do.call(what=rbind)`, where the formals for `do.call` are `function(what, args, quote, envir)`. Since in this latter expression I explicitly assign to `what=`, the `|>` placement goes to the next argument, which in this case is `args=` and what we need.

Answer (score 0):

`sub` the backslashes away, `strsplit` at slashes, remove zero char element at the beginning, `rbind` and `mode` to numeric.

```
> s <- el(strsplit(sub('\\\\', '', x), '/'))
> strsplit(subset(s, nzchar(s)), ',') |> do.call(what='rbind') |> `mode<-`('numeric')
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    2    5    6    2    5    0    0    0     0
[2,]    0    0    8    1    4   NA    2    4    0     0
[3,]    5    6    2    5    0    0    7    8    3     2
```

<sup>*Note:* Also not sure where the single backslash in the OP comes from, probably some sort of printing issue.</sup>

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(x)
"/0,2,5,6,2,5,0,0,0,0/0,0,8,1,4,,2,4,0,0/5,6,2,5,0,0,7,8,3,2\\"
```